# Endomorphisms of the multiplicative group over a non-reduced complex analytic space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, group-schemes

Let $S_n$ be the (usually) non-reduced complex analytic space corresponding to the ring $\mathbb{C}[X]/(X^{n+1})$ (the underlying topological space of $S_n$ is a point, and $S_0$ is a reduced point).

Let $G_n$ denote the product $\mathbb{G}_m \times S_n$ in the category of complex analytic spaces, which we consider as a complex analytic group space over $S_n$.  ($\mathbb{G}_m$ is the multiplicative group over $\mathbb{C}$.)

Let $\operatorname{End}_{S_n}(G_n)$ denote the endomorphisms of $G_n$ in the category of complex analytic groups over $S_n$.

**Question.** Is it true that $\operatorname{End}_{S_n}(G_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Equivalently, is the map $\operatorname{End}_{S_n}(G_n) \to \operatorname{End}_{S_0}(G_0)$ (induced by base change $S_0 \to S_n$) injective?  (I know that this map is surjective, and that $\operatorname{End}_{S_0}(G_0) = \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{G}_m) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.)

Ideally I'd like a reference which states this directly, or from which I can deduce it quickly.

I can think of two ways to try to prove this:

1. Direct calculation in the Hopf algebra.  I think I could probably work this out, but I would prefer to cite a reference if one exists.
2. If I wanted the analogous result for schemes instead of complex analytic spaces, I would use SGA 3, Exp. IX, Cor. 3.4.  It seems likely that the deformation theory of group schemes used in SGA 3 ought to work in the same way for complex analytic spaces.  But there's a lot of machinery involved here, so I would not want to invoke this unless it is clearly written down somewhere.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but doesn't $\mathbb{G}_{m,S_1}$ have many endomorphisms which restrict to the constant map, no? Take $z\mapsto 1+ \epsilon t$ for any choice of $t$. This shows that $\mathbb{G}_m$ sits inside $End(...)$.

Comment: The OP states that $\text{End}_{S_n}(G_n)$ denotes the group of endomorphisms of $G_n$ as a group object in the category of complex analytic spaces over $S_n$.  With this convention, the question has a positive answer, and can be proved by induction on $n$.  The "usual" argument applies in the category of complex analytic spaces: the kernel of the restriction homomorphism from $\text{End}_{S_n}(G_n)$ to $\text{End}_{S_{n-1}}(G_{n-1})$ equals the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of holomorphic vector fields on $\mathbb{G}_m$ that are appropriately invariant with respect to the group action.

Comment: When you do a power series expansion about the group identity, $1$, for such a holomorphic vector field, you get the same conclusion whether you work in the ring of germs of holomorphic functions or the ring of (not-necessarily-convergent) power series: the holomorphic vector field must be zero.  This contrasts with the case of $\mathbb{G}_a$, where there are nonzero vector fields.

Comment: Thanks Jason!  That is a fairly direct argument